# Single result from two group Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I would like to take **single** value from the following strings(HTML tag).

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="6857842162548399092:-3372646398158034589" autocomplete="off" />
```

OR

```
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[9028765775789786807:-4669779095536779687]]></update>
```

For `<input>` tag, the expression is

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id=".*\:javax.faces.ViewState\:.*" value="[^"]+".*\/>
```

For `<update>` tag, the expression is

```
<update .*><!\[CDATA\[(.*?.*)\]\]><\/update>
```

In need single result `685784..89` or `90287..87`.

The expression have to get single result for `<input ...>` or `<update....>`.

Comment: By single result do you mean in the same capture group?

Comment: Yes. I don't how to do single regular expression for these string (input or update tag)

Comment: You didn't specify the associated language or regex engine so try this https://regex101.com/r/f0uZ3I/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two with an `|`(*"OR"*).

Assuming the PCRE regex flavour:

```
(?|(?:<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id=".*\:javax.faces.ViewState\:.*" value="(?<value>[^"]+)".*\/>)|(?:<update .*?><!\[CDATA\[(?<value>.*?)\]\]><\/update>))
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/f3FWVc/2)

Comment: I don't think `Group value1` and `Group value2` are the same capture group as requested by OP

Comment: @PhuNgo Yes, you are right; fixed that with a branch reset group.